# Auto select the data in <select> <options> tag

Tags: php, html, session

I have a form which a user fills up and hits "Save & Next" which will take them to another page where the user can upload images and hit "Final Submit". They can also go back to the previous page to edit the data.

At that time, all the data he had previously filled up should be displayed on the text box. I have used session variable to store the data and display it.

I am stuck in the drop down box.

```
 <select name="District">
      <option value="East">East</option>
      <option value="West">West</option>
      <option value="North">North</option>
      <option value="South">South</option>
 </select>
```

When the user submits, I am storing the selected value in Session `$_SESSION['District'] = $_POST['District'];` and when the user clicks back to go the previous page, I need to auto select that option value in the drop down.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `array` would make it easier.

```
<?php
$options = array(
    'East', 'West', 'North', 'South',
);
?>
<select name="District">
    <?php foreach($options as $option) { ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $option; ?>" <?php echo (isset($_SESSION['District']) && $_SESSION['District'] == $option) ? "selected" : "" ?>><?php echo $option; ?></option>
    <?php } ?>
</select>
```

Comment: all the answers are correct yours its much easier quick. thumbs up

Comment: Thanks buddy... this one is the easiest among all correct!

Answer (score 1):

Check value in session and if matches set the attibute selected

```
<select name="District">
      <option <?php if (!empty($_POST['District']) && $_POST['District'] == 'East'){ echo 'selected'; }?> value="East">East</option>
      <option <?php if (!empty($_POST['District']) && $_POST['District'] == 'West'){ echo 'selected'; }?> value="West">West</option>
      <option  <?php if (!empty($_POST['District']) && $_POST['District'] == 'North'){ echo 'selected'; }?> value="North">North</option>
      <option <?php if (!empty($_POST['District']) && $_POST['District'] == 'South'){ echo 'selected'; }?> value="South">South</option>
 </select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just check the selected value against the one stored in session.
Your option will look like this:

```
<option value="East" <?php echo ($_SESSION['District']=="East" ? "selected" : ""; ?>>East</option>
```

And the right one will be selected

Answer (score 1):

```
<select name="District">
    <option value="East" <?php if($_SESSION['District'] == "East"):?>selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>>East</option>
    ... Repeat with all options ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Use below code:

```
<select name="District">
      <option value="East" <?php echo ($_SESSION['District'] == "East") ? "selected" : "" ?>>East</option>
      <option value="West" <?php echo ($_SESSION['District'] == "West") ? "selected" : "" ?>>West</option>
      <option value="North" <?php echo ($_SESSION['District'] == "North") ? "selected" : "" ?>>North</option>
      <option value="South" <?php echo ($_SESSION['District'] == "South") ? "selected" : "" ?>>South</option>
 </select>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<option value="East" <?php echo isset($_SESSION['District']) && $_SESSION['District'] == 'East' ? 'selected="selected"' :'' ;?> >East</option>
<option value="West" <?php echo isset($_SESSION['District']) && $_SESSION['District'] == 'West' ? 'selected="selected"' :'' ;?>>West</option>
<option value="North" <?php echo isset($_SESSION['District']) && $_SESSION['District'] == 'North' ? 'selected="selected"' :'' ;?>>North</option>
<option value="South" <?php echo isset($_SESSION['District']) && $_SESSION['District'] == 'South' ? 'selected="selected"' :'' ;?>>South</option>
```